# How should I fix "error in knn(): 'train' and 'class' have different lengths"?

Tags: r, knn

I am attempting to use the knn() function in the class package to solve a problem.  I have split the iris dataset into 50% training data and 50% test data.  I am attempting to predict the variety variable using sepal width and petal width.  My knn() call is as follows:

```
> predictions <- knn(iris.train[, c(1:2)], iris.test[, c(1:2)], iris.train[, 3], k = 10)
```

In this instance, columns 1 and 2 of iris.train and iris.test are sepal width and petal width.  Column 3 of both datasets is the variety variable as a factor.  I continuously get the error that 'train' and 'class' have different lengths.  When checking dimensions of what I pass into the function, this is what I get:

```
> dim(iris.train[, c(1:2)])
[1] 75  2

> dim(iris.test[, c(1:2)])
[1] 75  2

> dim(iris.train[, 3])
[1] 75  1
```

So I would assume that I'm missing something.  How can I resolve the issue of 'train' and 'class' being different lengths?  Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Can you provide your full code? Are you using the `class` package? I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `cl` argument should be a factor/vector of length equal to the number of rows in `train`.  If you check `length(iris.train[,3])`, you'll see that it is equal to 1
(i.e. it is a one-column frame), which is not the same as the number of rows in `train`.

Try this:

```
predictions <- knn(iris.train[, c(1:2)], iris.test[, c(1:2)], iris.train[[3]], k = 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  That worked for me.  Just out of curiosity, what does the double bracket mean in R?  When I say "iris.train[[3]]", what does R interpret that to mean?

Comment: note that `iris.train` is a list. When we use `[`, we get a list of the elements selected. For example `iris.train[c(1,3,5)]` will return a list of the selected elements from `iris.train`. Likewise, `iris.train[3]` will also return a list of the selected elements (in this case, as single column).  However, `iris.train[[3]]` will return the third element, which in this case will be a vector of values.. My explanation here is insufficent - best to check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el